An internal error occurred during: "Refreshing workspace". Eclipse 2024-03 fresh install
at importing project time I already got this error
An internal error occurred during: "Refreshing workspace".
class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaNature cannot be cast to class org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject (org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaNature and org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject are in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @27833d58)


Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2024-03 (4.31.0)
Build id: 20240307-1437


java.vm.specification.version=17
java.vm.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
java.vm.version=17.0.10+7

Eclipse IDE + Quarkus Tools: fresh install
Importing project into workspace, but it not even compile

Try it again with 2024-06. RC1 can be found through  https://www.eclipse.org/lists/epp-dev/msg06899.html .

Fixed in another code path in 2024-03 via https://github.com/eclipse-jeetools/webtools.javaee/issues/10, and with systematic changes throughout other WTP repositories for 2024-06.
